# How to create a session object?

Tags: java, session, servlets, dwr

I am creating a login page for my web application. I want to create a session object whenever
a new user logged in. I know the concept of sessions, but i didnt used that before. Can i do it with a simple class. Or, i have to move to servlet.
If i shall do it with a simple class means, how to create a session object.

---

### This is my scenario...

**The HTML CODE:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>User Name: </td><td><input id="uName"  class="required" type="text" 
    size="5" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password: </td><td><input id="pwd"  class="required" type="text" size="5"
    onclick="login()"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**The JS Code:**

```
function login(){
var userDetails = { uName : null, pwd : null };
dwr.util.getValues(userDetails);//Yes, i am using DWR.
LoginAuthentication.doLogin(userDetails, loginResult);
}

 function loginResult(nextPage){
window.location.href = nextPage;
}
```

**The Java Code:**

```
public class LoginAuthentication
{
public String doLogin(User user) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    String userName = user.getUserName();
    boolean loginResult = verifyUser(user);//Another method that verifies user details with the DB.
    if (loginResult == true){
        /* Here I have to create session object,
          and i want to add the current username in that object. How to do it.*/

        return "MainPage.html";
    }
    else{

        return "loginRetryPage.html";

    }
   }
```

---

The concept that was given to me about session is pretty simple and clear. I have to create a session object after  a valid user input & add the user name to that object, Destroy the object when logout was clicked. But i didnt worked on sessions before. I mean, i dont know the syntax to create a session variable.

**How shall i create a session Object here?**

Any suggestions would be more appreciative!!!

**Thanks in Advance!!!**

Comment: what is "The java code"? What class is it in? Is it a servlet?

Comment: @skaffman: Oh, Sorry. I ll update my  question now.

Comment: That doesn't really help... what is `LoginAuthentication`, and how does it relate to anything else?

Comment: @skaffman: Its just a class name. I removed the other methods. Maybe i dont know how to name a class according to its purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a servlet a session is obtained with the following line:

```
Session session = request.getSession();
```

And to get the `request` object with DWR, you do ([see here](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/server/javaapi.html)):

```
WebContext ctx = WebContextFactory.get();
HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getHttpServletRequest();
```

(The `HttpServletRequest` contains all data about the HTTP request that has been sent by the browser to the server)

Comment: What is the "request"? What is its purpose?

Comment: Thanks for your instant update. I went thro your link, it seems it ll be useful to me. But, can you explain me what is WebContext. What it ll do? What will happen if i add these two lines? WebContext ctx = WebContextFactory.get();
req = ctx.getHttpServletRequest();

Comment: yes, it will. The above three lines will give you the Session object, where you can add things and retrieve things.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to always use  request.getSession(false); after successful login.

Comment: What do you mean by after successful login. Its about checking username & pass with DB or creating a session object.